# Python-like list unpacking in C#?

Tags: c#, iterable-unpacking

In python, I can do something like this:

```
List=[3, 4]

def Add(x, y):
    return x + y

Add(*List) #7
```

Is there any way to do this or something similar in C#? Basically I want to be able to pass a List of arguments to an arbitrary function, and have them applied as the function's parameters without manually unpacking the List and calling the function explicitly specifying the parameters.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, the closest would be reflection, but that is on the slow side... but look at [MethodInfo.Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a89hcwhh.aspx)...

Answer (score 7):

You can use the params keyword when defining your method and then you can directly put your list (after calling ToArray) in your method call.

```
public static void UseParams(params object[] list)
{
        for (int i = 0; i < list.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(list[i] + " ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
}
```

...which you can later call with the following.

```
object[] myObjArray = { 2, 'b', "test", "again" };
UseParams(myObjArray);
```

For reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx

Answer (score 1):

you cant, you can do things that are close with a bit of hand waving (either yield to a foreach, or add a foreach extension method on the collection that takes a lambda), but nothing as elegant as you get in python.

Answer (score 0):

```
Func<List<float>, float> add = l => l[0] + l[1];
var list = new List<float> { 4f, 5f };
add(list); // 9
```

or:

```
Func<List<float>, float> add = l => l.Sum();
var list = new List<float> { 4f, 5f };
add(list); // 9
```

Is the closest you get in c# considering it's statically typed. You can look into F#'s pattern matching for exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Your first suggestion will only work for lists with 2 elements.  To make your first suggestion more general without using Sum() you could use Func<List<float>, float> add = l => l.Aggregate((float)0, (aggregation, current) => aggregation + current);  But Sum() seems to be the way to go here :)