# Lua style parameters in C#

Tags: c#, lua, parameter-passing

In Lua parameters can be passed into a function by unpacking a list and the function being called receives those parameter values in it's named parameter items...

```
local function someFunkyFunc( firstParam, secondParam, thirdParam )
  print( firstParam, secondParam, thirdParam ) -- prints the three parameters
end

local tbl = { "first", "second", "third" } -- parameter values to be passed

someFunkyFunc( unpack( tbl ) ) -- calling the function with named parameters
```

Is this possible (in some form) in C#? If so, how?

This is not the same as Python because we're talking about Lua, not Python.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python-like list unpacking in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/568280/python-like-list-unpacking-in-c)

Comment: Duplicate talks about python, but python does the same thing as lua by the sounds of it (`someFunkyFunc(**tbl)`)

Comment: So do lots of languages, but we're talking about a specific language and it's notation.

Comment: The language is irrelevant, you're talking about passing arguments via an array of values. The answer in the duplicate shares details with your accepted answer (albeit in not as much detail)....

Comment: The language is not irrelevant. It is exactly the point. I want to know how to do something in one language that I can in another specific language. Telling me how to do it in Python doesn't tell me how to do it in C# or if it is possible. Yes, this is a similar question, but knowing HOW to do it in Python is completely different to doing it in C# because in one the language itself supports the option and in another it is a library which provides the capability.

Comment: @MattW In C# it's not actually a library, but also a core function of the language, it just doesn't have it's own syntax.

Comment: I think the key point here (which I'm trying hard to make) is that this question is not a duplicate of the Python question because they are different languages. The python answer does not help me in C#, which is the whole point of the question. I am about to modify the question to make it clear that I am not looking for a Yes/No answer (not that the Python post has that either.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can assign the method to a `Delegate` and then use `DynamicInvoke` to provide an array of the parameters:

```
Action<object, object, object> action = someFunkyFunc;
object[] tbl = { "first", "second", "third" };
action.DynamicInvoke(tbl);
```

Note that this will come with a notable performance cost, and a loss of static typing.

Alternatively you could use reflection to get the `MethodInfo` for `someFunkyFunc`can call `Invoke` on it, although it will have the same drawbacks.

Comment: What if there are suddenly 4 arguments? This is still a fixed list of parameters.

Comment: @PatrickHofman The same is true of `unpack`.  The onus is on you to ensure that the array has the exact right number, and types, of values.  In this case they're just hard coded, like in the OP's case, because it's an example.  In real code the array would be generated dynamically, and the delegate could *also* be computed dynamically, so long as you ensure that they match.

Comment: By jove he's got it! Thanks to you, too!

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not method to unpack a list and provide them as arguments to a method with dynamic typing and argument count.

The best you can do is pass in a dictionary of string and object (`Dictionary<string, object>`).

If you don't need the parameter names, you can also use `params object[] values`.

Another option is to use Reflection, where you map the method and its arguments dynamically, however, that is an error-prone approach which I would try to prevent taking.

Comment: The fact that it's just wrong to say that you can't do it.  Why would someone upvote it?

Comment: So you can unpack a list and transform them into method arguments?

Comment: Yes, you can do that.

Comment: And how is that?

Comment: I have an answer showing *multiple* ways.  Considering you've already commented on it, I know you've read it, so I have no idea why you'd post such a comment.